# How to create 2 column layout dynamically in android?

Tags: android, button, scroll, imageview

### **MOCK UP**

[image: 2-column layout]

### Overview

All are the **ImageView** with **buttons** with Scrolling

### Requirement

I want to implement 2-Column fix layout for the **image** display.

And from the press the **Button** , it would be **detect** that **image.**

If only 1 image came then it display only one image in layout.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `GridView`.Look into [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) for your reference. For **2 column layout** give `android:numColumns = "2"`. Load the `ImageView` and `Button` dynamically using `Adapter`.
For this,

1.Create an xml which hold the `GridView`.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridFriends"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"/>
```

2.To define the contents of the GridView, create another XML layout which will hold the ImageView and the ImageButton.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@null" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center">
        <Button>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Create a `customAdapter` for populating the `GridView` dynamically.Look [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/02/29/custom-gridview-in-android-a-simple-example/) for creating custom adapter.In that `CustomAdapter` `getView()` inflate the layout(in step 2)

Answer (score 0):

Create One ScrollView with LinearLayout as main layout with orientation as Vertical. Add linear laoyut's how many you want to parent payout with two buttons like below code

```
LinearLayout llay = new LinearLayout(this); 
llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); 

LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
<scrollview>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation = "vertical"
        android:height = "match_parent"
        android:width = "match_parent"
    >
      //for two column image view
        <LinearLayout
            android:id = "@+id/image_view_container1"
            android:orientation = "horiZontal"
            android:height = "match_parent"
            android:width = "0dp"
            android:weight = "1">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id = "@+id/image_view_01"
                android:orientation = "vertical"
                android:height = "match_parent"
                android:width = "0dp"
                android:weight = "1">

                <ImageView>
                <Button>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id = "@+id/image_view_02"
                android:orientation = "vertical"
                android:height = "match_parent"
                android:width = "0dp"
                android:weight = "1">

                <ImageView>
                <Button>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I told that, I want dynamically list not static and it should be detect button click...
Go through the question again, Thank you for reply.

Comment: sorry. I have improved my ans for your need.Please look into it.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I just check it out, if it solve my problem then I accept your answer. :)